# Login Prompt while opening Office document in SharePoint2013 Extranet with Forms authentication

Tags: document-library, forms-authentication, office-integration

We have setup the SharePoint 2013 extranet site with FBA authentication of Extradium tool.
We have 1 WFE,1 APP & 1 DB server in our farm.We are currently facing issue while opening office document.

When user tries to open office document he gets a login prompt.We want to avoid this login prompt for user.
As the site will be used by external users from their local machine,browser related settings are not helpful in this case.

Already checked this blog https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/steve_chen/multiple-logon-while-open-office-document-from-sharepoint/.....

Any help is appreciate...